# After installed Ubuntu my hard disk failed

Tags: hard-drive

I’ve met a problem here which is after I’ve installed Ubuntu into my Hard disk and booted into it , it’s said my disk is likely to fail soon. But here’s the question, the Hard disk works perfectly fine before I install Ubuntu, It only fail after Ubuntu is finish install. Can somebody help me with this? Much appreciated

Comment: Hard drives can fail at any time.  They put a MTBF (Mean Time Between Failures) on drive statistics but these are only averages for ideal environments like heat, cold, electricity, etc.  It is always best to have backups and backups of things that are important to you.  Never worry about a drive working fine before installing an OS on to it.  I have had drives that were working "perfectly" fine before I scrubbed them and they went bad during the scrub.

Comment: It's a coincidence. An unfortunate coincidence. Ubuntu does not destroy hard drives.

Comment: Before you installed Ubuntu, you probably weren't using any software that checked for indications of *failing hardware*, so you should be *glad* Ubuntu has detected it before it occurred (*you have warning that the drive may fail in the weeks, months ahead*). Either way it's a result of you installing software that monitors hardware health but your issue is *failing* hardware that isn't on-topic on this site.

Comment: FYI:  I'm involved in QA (*Quality Assurance*) with Ubuntu and *flavors*, and saw the indications when the feature was introduced *long ago*  (*you gave no specifics as to what Ubuntu product you're talking about so I'll be generic too*).  As the issue only occurs on a box I use in QA-testing I have no data on the box I value & thus I'm ignoring it.  When the drive fails; I'll just drop in a newer drive - but it's a warning of a failure that will occur, though it's unknown when it'll fail & data will be lost. How you act with that knowledge is up to you.

Comment: When my own box (*used in QA*) appeared with *failure notice*, all I did was verify the message was appearing with valid justification (*it was,* https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), commented I'd seen the notice & it appeared appropriate for a *failing* drive (*in my case the validation had only just been added*) etc.. I'm sure if you check, you'll find the same; your *unstated* Ubuntu system is reporting on a disk drive with *unhealthy* SMART stats.   (*ps:  even if a drive keeps working, it may be working very slowly needing to perform functions many times due to health*)